# What kind of error is this "c(.text+0x7): relocation truncated to fit: 8 .data"

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation, i386

I was compiling/linking my program

```
i386-gcc -o output.lnx func.opc mainc.opc
```

and I kept getting that error. I honestly have no idea what this means.

Any clue?

thanks,

Comment: .opc files are opcode files, produced by    i-386-as -o func.opc func.s

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Then how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean object files? opcodes are generally associated with VMs such as the Java or .NET VMs, not with physical architectures like i386. It's more common to use `.o` as an extension on i386.

Comment: Now, why and how are you generating this raw assembler? If there's a problem with said assembly it could produce such an error at the link phase. And those weird extensions have tipped me off to the fact that you might be doing something unusual here...

Comment: It looks like you have an out-of-bounds value, i.e. a value larger than the location you place it in. Given the error message, it looks like you are trying to place something in an 8-bit field.

Comment: Show the instruction at `.text + 0x7`. Is it a near jump/call (to a location too far away) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a symptom of having too much code or data in the program.  The relocation at offset 7 in .text segment (code) has been compiled with a fixed size (2 or 4), but the data/instruction it is referring to is more than 64k or 2G away.

Other than that, I can't tell you how to fix it without actually seeing the object files. Useful tools for pinpointing the problem are `objdump` (with flags `-dr`) and `readelf` programs.